# rails fields_for object is nil, when I try to access an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fields-for

Have three models:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :offer_items
end

class OfferItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :offer
  belongs_to :partner_product
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :partner_product
end

class PartnerProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :offer_items
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :offer_items
end
```

In the form where offer is edited, there is fields_for to edit offer_item

```
<% f.fields_for :offer_items do |offer_item_form| -%>
 <div class='offer_item'>
   <%= render :partial => 'offer_item_fields', :locals => {:offer_item_form => offer_item_form}%>
      </div>
<% end -%>
```

The code chunk in the partial:

```
<%= offer_item_form.object.partner_product.name%>
```

throws an error

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
>
> Extracted source (around line #29):

```
<%= offer_item_form.object.partner_product.name%>
```

but when I don't ask the name, like this

```
<%= offer_item_form.object.partner_product%>
<%= debug( offer_item_form.object.partner_product)%>
```

get in the browser:

```
#<PartnerProduct:0x007fa8785ff938>

--- !ruby/ActiveRecord:PartnerProduct 
attributes: 
id: 1
partner_id: 586
name: a
stock_volume: 0
source_price: 0
created_at: 2012-05-31 14:05:47 Z
updated_at: 2012-05-31 14:05:47 Z
```

I'm not just wondering, why I can't access a 'name' attribute and changed the partner_product to nil, but I really should show it. Any help is welcome!
Thanks

Comment: I forgot: Rails 3.0.5,gem "simple_form"